# Python Mail MIMEMultipart (.setpayload) printing \n in logs instead going into next line

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to send mail through MIMEMultipart including EMail body with set payload to capture HTML/Image & Error logs , everything seems working except that the error logs are not going into the next line when error has default '\n' from the source lambda, because of this , it doesn't look reading friendly at all. I have tried to replace '\n with 
 in my source lambda but this time the logs is printing 
 instead of going in next line .Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Here is small snippet of my code: I have added #event in the below code which is coming from my first lambda as payload.

```
import json
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import *
from email.encoders import *
from email.message import EmailMessage
from mimetypes import *
import smtplib, email

messag = MIMEMultipart()
messag.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
#event payload coming from first lambda
event = {'Source': 'Model', 'ModelName': 'Test  checks', 'Target': ['email'], 'EmailSubject': 'Alert  Notification - Test  checks failed', 'EmailBody': ' The lambda has failed for Test  checks<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Error_Msg</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2891, in get_loc\\n    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)\\n  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\\n  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc\\n  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\\n  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item\\nKeyError: \'dealguid\'\\n\\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 569, in lambda_handler\\n    dqm_results_wfp,temp_deep_dive_results,alert_message,ap_comp_columns,payload_id = perform_data_quality_checks(json_str,engine)\\n  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 409, in perform_data_quality_checks\\n    payload_id = list(result[\'dealguid\'])[0]\\n  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__\\n    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)\\n  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2893, in get_loc\\n    raise KeyError(key) from err\\nKeyError: \'dealguid\'\\n</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table> please refer to corresponding lambda function Test  checks in Dev to debug the issue. ', 'AdditionalRec': ['exampleid.com'}

messag.set_payload(event['EmailBody'])
messag['To'] = "exampleid.com"
   
messag['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
server = smtplib.SMTP('example.com', '25')
server.sendmail('exampleid.com' , 'exampleid.com', messag.as_string())
```

output I am getting in mail :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 397, in traverse_json\n dqm_json_df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(json_string))\n File "/opt/python/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in _json_normalize\n if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):\n File "/opt/python/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in <genexpr>\n if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):\nAttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 569, in lambda_handler\n dqm_results_wfp,temp_deep_dive_results,alert_message,ap_comp_columns,payload_id = perform_data_quality_checks(json_str,engine)\n File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 408, in perform_data_quality_checks\n result = traverse_json(json_payload)\n File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 399, in traverse_json\n dqm_json_df = pd.json_normalize(json_string)\n File "/opt/python/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in _json_normalize\n if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):\n File "/opt/python/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py", line 270, in <genexpr>\n if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):\nAttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'\n
```

Comment: Well you explicitely use `\\n` to say that you want two characters a backslash and a n, and get that. If you want a newline instead, use a single backslash (`\n`).

Comment: \\n instances is due to window next line , however single \n also not going into next line. you can see printed single \n in the beginning of the line ,  do you have any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting the body as HTML and add a content-type header of `text/html`.

It does not make sense to use `\n` for formatting then, you should stick to html elements and replace the `\\n` in your boby with *breaks*: `<br/>`.

Comment: yes your are correct but replacing "\\n" to" <br />"  is not resulting in next line, it's again printing the logs with "<br/>"  `Traceback (most recent call last): <br/> File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 556, in lambda_handler <br/> sql_log_query = text("""INSERT INTO `data_alerts`.`log_table` <br/> NameError: name 'text' is not defined`